Exiting fullscreen when going to different location on website
I am trying to make a website which acts like an app with the add to homescreen function on Safari IOS. It looks fine on the homepage but when i try to go to another page it exits fullscreen and I cant get it to stay whatever i search for or try.
My code looks something like this.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // iOS web app full screen hacks.
        if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
            // make all link remain in web app mode.
            $('a').click(function() {
                window.location = $(this).attr('href');
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<a href="/pagetwo">pagetwo</a>

This is the head for both pages.

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="page" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/iphone-startup.png">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/out.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvsO0EvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

I got all of this code from http://www.onlywebpro.com/tutorials/mobile-content/optimizing-full-screen-mobile-web-app-for-ios So my suspicion is that because it is so old there are some things people on here could point out for me are wrong. Thanks.
